# C++ app for IPAD with C++Lucene library

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, ipad, visual-c++

I am planning to build an app in C++ for ipad. I have never build any app for ios. I want to know whether is it possible to write a C++ app using Lucene library in ipad. Can i write the code in visual c++ and compile it in xcode. Can i use the same code to work in mac os as well? I really wanted to build the app in Java so it works every where but unfortunately I pad doesnt support java.

Please provide me some good suggestions to build this app.

Thank you.

Comment: I'd quintuple-plus-one your post if I could, @CarlNorum.  However, sadly, the people to which that article is tailored will never read it because it doesn't answer their problem.

Answer (score 2):

No.  You can't build for iPad in Visual Studio.

You can include C++ in "Objective-C++" files, named .mm, but you will have to learn a minimum of Objective-C in which to include your C++ code.

As for using the same code for mac, it depends on how well you separate your logic from your display code - you can reuse some code, but you can't simply hit "build for Mac" and have iPad apps magically run on the Mac.  You'll have to, at the very least, build a totally separate interface.

Answer (score 2):

Building apps for iOS, etc requires some simple steps :

- Buy a Mac
- Learn some Objective-C

There is no other way around that makes sense.

Comment: Surely if enough people ask the same question, there will be, though, right?!